# Lambda - object mutation persists between lambda calls

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I came across something when running a lambda in AWS and I am trying to understand why it is behaving the way it is.

I have this lambda here:

```
const myObj = {
  test: 111
};

function testFunc(obj: any) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  obj.test = 222;
}

export const handler = middy(async (event: any) => {
  testFunc(myObj);
  return {
    statusCode: 200
  }
})
```

When I run the code the first time the cloudwatch logs for the lambda show the following:

```
{"test":111}
```

However when I run the code the second time the cloudwatch logs for the lambda show the following:

```
{"test":222}
```

My understanding of Lambdas is that they each time they run they will run in a new instance so no "state" of objects or anything should be kept in the Node environment as it should be fresh every time.

Is my understanding correct? If so then why is the state of `myObj` persisting across different invokes?

Also - the most bizarre thing is that this function has been working fine for months (ie running a new instance of the code every time and always returning `{"test":111}`, it just suddenly started acting this new way after a deployment I did that did not touch the function whatsoever.

Thanks

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect -- environments are reused. You might enjoy reading this series of articles about how AWS Lambda operates: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a concepts of cold start and warm start.

Cold start works as you expect: new execution environment and no re-use of previous run state.

Warm start on the other hand uses a previously-created Lambda function execution environment and re-uses its state. This is an optimization technique and warm functions have much faster start time. Execution environments can remain warm for a limited period of time before being destroyed. When no available execution environments remain, the next invocation will be a cold start.

This article might be helpful: [Understanding AWS Lambda Cold Start and Warm Start](https://medium.com/@sushantraje2000/understanding-aws-lambda-cold-start-and-warm-start-4f8297074ee).